# Install Visual Studio 2015 community edition on Windows 7

Tags: installation, visual-studio-2015

I an trying to install Visual Studio 2015 community edition on Windows 7 64-bit.

For some reason, the installer says "Setup Blocked" with an error "This version of Visual Studio requires a computer with a newer version of Windows".

[image]

what should be done in order to install setup completely.

Comment: Do you have Windows 7 Service Pack 1?

Comment: no it windows 7 Professional version 6.1 (Build 7600)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

VS 2015 and VS 2013 Update 5 require Windows 7 Service Pack 1 or later.

[Learn how to install Windows 7 Service Pack 1](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/install-windows-7-service-pack-1)

Support for Windows 7 RTM ended on [April 9, 2013](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/lifecycle).

Comment: Downloaded Windows service pack 1 from [link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5842)